# fscanf printing replacement character

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    //opening collection.txt using ptr 
    FILE *ptr;
    
    char data[1000];
    ptr = fopen("collection.txt", "r");
    
    printf("Hello world \n");
    
    fscanf(ptr, "%s", data);
    printf("%s \n", data);
    
    fclose(ptr);
    
    return 0;       
}
```

collection.txt:

```
hi my name is
```

When I run this program I'm getting :

```
Hello world 
P7k
```

P7k is a memory location I assume.

I've looked at multiple websites and articles and I'm unable to figure out what I can do to print the text in collection.txt

Comment: Add a check that `fopen` succeeded: `if (ptr == NULL) { printf("Could not open file\n"); return 1; }` Also *always* check what all `scanf` functions (like `fscanf`) [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude used the if condition but had no luck with that :(
checked about the return value of fscanf but it didn't help much

Comment: Do `fopen` succeed, and `ptr` is not a null pointer after the `fopen` call? And `fscanf` returns `1`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yup I did that exactly, but not luck. And yes fscanf returns 1

Comment: If `fopen` succeeds ans if `fscanf` returns 1, that means the there is a file called collection.txt in the currrent directory of the program, and `fscanf` has read the string "P7k` from that file. Check all that that.The current directory might not be what you think is.

Comment: Also replace `fscanf(ptr, "%s", data);` with `fgets(data, sizeof(data), ptr);` and see what happens.

Comment: If all works, then the file you open isn't a plain text file. If you open it in a plain text editor, or use a command to type it as plain text, or (if you're on e.g. Linux use the `file` command to classify it), is it really what you expect it to be? You don't have multiple `collection.txt` on your drive? How did you create this file?

Answer (score 1):

Problems include

**Not testing for `fopen()` success**

```
FILE *ptr;
// add
if (ptr == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Fail to open\n");
  return -1;
}
```

**Not testing for `fscanf()` success**

```
// fscanf(ptr, "%s", data);
if (fscanf(ptr, "%s", data) != 1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Fail to read\n");
  return -1;
}
```

**Not limiting input**

```
char data[1000];
// fscanf(ptr, "%s", data);
fscanf(ptr, "%999s", data);
```

**Not reporting all data**

`"%s"` does not save white space, so white-space from the file is not printed.

Use `fgets()` to read a *line* of input.  To read all, use a loop.

```
while (fgets(data, sizeof data, ptr)) {
  printf("%s", ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`%s` only scans until it finds a white character. My suggestion would be to scan the file character by character (`%c`) until you reach the end of the file.

Something like:

```
while(!feof(ptr)) { 
  fscanf(ptr, %c, data + counter); counter++;
}
```

Comment: Please format your answer properly.

Comment: See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359).

Comment: Code risks overflowing `ptr`.  When loop completes, `data[]` is not certainly yet a _string_ as no _null character_ appended causing UB in the following `printf("%s \n", data);`.